# With multiple players, force only one player to be playing [React Player]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-player

I have similar issue https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues/470

> After going through many plugins, this is the best media player for React I've found so thank you!

I'm using this just for audio with the File player type. I have a playlist which is just a list of multiple  elements and I'd like to force it to only play one player at a time. Thus, if a player is playing and you press play on another player, then the first player stops. Currently, it will play any and all players simultaneously.

How can I force only one player to play on the page at any given time?

Here's my DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-stonebraker-9q3zi?file=/src/App.js

Thank you if anyone could help me :)